# SQL Server INSERT in an AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server, and I'm trying to build a simple update trigger that writes a row to a staging table whenever the column ceu_amount is updated from zero to any number greater than zero.

From using PRINT statements, I know that the variables are containing the correct values to execute the INSERT statement, but no rows are being inserted.

Can you help?

```
CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[TRG_Product_Function_Modified] ON [dbo].[Product_Function]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --
    -- Variable definitions
    --
    DECLARE @product_code_new as varchar(31)
    DECLARE @product_code_old as varchar(31)

    --
    -- Check if the staging table needs to be updated.
    -- 
    SELECT @product_code_new = product_code FROM Inserted where ISNULL(ceu_amount,0) > 0;
    SELECT @product_code_old = product_code FROM Deleted  where ISNULL(ceu_amount,0) = 0;
        IF  @product_code_new IS NOT NULL 
        AND @product_code_old IS NOT NULL 
            INSERT INTO Product_Function_Staging VALUES (@product_code_new,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code looks suspicious to me..

```
SELECT @product_code_new = product_code FROM Inserted where ISNULL(ceu_amount,0) > 0;
    SELECT @product_code_old = product_code FROM Deleted  where ISNULL(ceu_amount,0) = 0;
        IF  @product_code_new IS NOT NULL 
        AND @product_code_old IS NOT NULL 
            INSERT INTO Product_Function_Staging VALUES (@product_code_new,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The above will work fine ,if there is only one row updated,what if there is more than one value..the product_code will default  to last value

You can change the above part of code to below

```
Insert into Product_Function_Staging 
select product_code ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from inserted where product_code is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get undetermined values for @product_code_new if there are more than one rows updated with ceu_amount>0; Similar for @product_code_old if more than one rows updated with ceu_amount NULL or equal 0.
Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use variables like that in a trigger, since what causes the trigger could be an update to more than one row, at which point you would have multiple rows in your updated and deleted tables.

I think we can more safely and efficiently make this insert with one simple query, though I'm assuming you have a unique key to use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[TRG_Product_Function_Modified] ON [dbo].[Product_Function]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Product_Function_Staging
    SELECT i.product_code, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM inserted i
        JOIN deleted d ON i.product_code = d.product_code -- assuming product_code is unique
    WHERE i.ceu_amount > 0 -- new value > 0
        AND ISNULL(d.ceu_amount, 0) = 0; -- old value null or 0
END;
```

I'm not sure where you need to check for nulls in your data, so I've made a best guess in the where clause.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_UPDATE]
       ON [dbo].[Customers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @CustomerId INT
       DECLARE @Action VARCHAR(50)

       SELECT @CustomerId = INSERTED.CustomerId       
       FROM INSERTED

       IF UPDATE(Name)
       BEGIN
              SET @Action = 'Updated Name'
       END

       IF UPDATE(Country)
       BEGIN
              SET @Action = 'Updated Country'
       END

       INSERT INTO CustomerLogs
       VALUES(@CustomerId, @Action)
END
```

Comment: I suggest editing this such that it refers to the OPs tables and columns. Also, `if update` doesn't care about the value of the update, only that the column was set, so I don't think this will work anyway.